# Кодировка в json и python

Tags: json, кодировка, unicode, python-3.8, перекодировка

Содержимое файла Dates_for_admin.json выглядит так:

```
{
    "Количество пользователей": 5
}
```

Там очень много букв и бэкслешов.
А содержимое файла ненужное.py выглядит так:

```
import json

with open("Dates_for_admin.json","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json_dict = json.load(file)
    json_dict["Количество пользователей"] += 1

with open("Dates_for_admin.json","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(json_dict,file)
```

После запуска ненужное.py содержимое файла Dates_for_admin.json
примерно выглядит так (если не ошибаюсь,это вроде кодировка юникод):

```
{"\u047\u036e\u043": 6}
```

Там очень много букв,цифр и бэкслешов.
Как сделать так,чтоб файл Dates_for_admin.json выглядит нормально,то есть так:

```
{
    "Количество пользователей": 6
}
```

И чтобы он не выглядел "по-юникодски"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте  `ensure_ascii=False`

`encoding="utf8"`  пишется без "-"

```
import json

with open("Dates_for_admin.json","r",encoding="utf8") as file:
    json_dict = json.load(file,  ensure_ascii=False)
    json_dict["Количество пользователей"] += 1

with open("Dates_for_admin.json","w",encoding="utf8") as file:
    json.dump(json_dict,file, ensure_ascii=False)
```